# Is it possible to pylint for a specific error code?

Tags: python, pylint

I want to pylint a project against unused imports to make upgrading a module easier (W0611).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just figured it out from some trial and error, a little hard to figure out by reading the docs only:

`pylint --disable=all --enable=W0611`